# What is the best way to get response for unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

I recently asked a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830383/how-to-retrieve-response-from-amazon-ses) and found that it is unanswered even after keeping bounties on it.

I didn't even get any response from any users (neither upvotes/downvotes nor comments/answers). What else should I try to get response for such questions if bounty system didn't work?

Comment: Nope. Bounties aren't refunded. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @Bart Bounty didn't work to me. Is there any other way for getting response to such unanswered questions?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question?

Comment: @apaul34208 I've updated my question with the link you've expected

Comment: Give it a few more days... You can't really say the bounty hasn't worked. It just hasn't worked yet.

Comment: @apaul34208 Usually I won't use bounties for questions, since I used to get response in S.O within seconds. May it be downvote/upvote, it helped me to discuss my problems at that instant. Now, I found this question odd for not getting answered.That's the reason I've raised this question

Comment: A certain percentage of questions never get answered, for various reasons.  Sometimes the subject matter is obscure.  Sometimes the OP is unresponsive.  Did you do what the commenter suggested on your question and toss an invalid email address at the API to see what response you get?

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have done what you should have to get an answer:

- Well Written Question
- Good Title
- Appropriate & Enough Tags
- Interacted with Commenters
- Placed Bounties

Sometimes you will end up with a question that no one looking has the answer to.  I've a few of those myself.  The only other thing I would suggest is to place a larger bounty on it, but you probably want to get your rep up to do that.

Comment: I think there is just too little incentive to look at the bottom of the queue of unanswered questions. A [gold badge for revival/necromancer pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268) (which I proposed to call **Persephone**) would IMHO help.