# Unanswered Questions: What am I still missing and what can I do to improve them?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

First, I'll note that I've read [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and even potential duplicates -e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324208/4594973). I believe I've taken the feedback in those answers into account, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I'd appreciate more precise thoughts and help, as I clearly must still be missing something.

I've asked a few questions, specifically these two -e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37942389/4594973) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735053/4594973). I seem to have done what's necessary to get a response, as per this response [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256671/4594973).

Still, my questions:

- barely get any views
- didn't get any up-votes
- seem to have no chance of ever getting attention, much less answered

On the views point, are my question titles simply crap? Are they mis-tagged? Am I just asking in the wrong place here (e.g. should I've gone to the gamedev, or math sites instead of SO)? Something else? I've looked at some higher-voted questions -e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4594973)- and, other than popularity, nothing in particular "jumps out" at me as obvious. I'm certainly not getting negative attention, like it happened [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268653/4594973).

On the votes point, I think my questions show research effort, which is supposed to be the expectation, and none of the few viewers who've visited even bothered to ask a clarifying question on a comment, so I'm under the impression that my questions were clear. Is this not the case?

OTOH, I've seen simple question posts that clearly show no research effort whatsoever -e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12058492/4594973), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/4594973)- get up-votes and even responses -perhaps due to the question being more popular. Should I just play ignorant when asking?

I understand that no one is required to up-vote anything, but no one down-voted any of them either, so what's going on? I would've expected down votes if they had been bad questions, so, why not up-votes? Are they simply not popular enough to be "useful"?

On the last point, it also seems that after a question gets buried in the unanswered queue, they barely stand a chance of getting any attention in the future. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27946387/4594973) has been showing up as the top-voted unanswered question, and it's been there for a year now. This appears to be a well-known issue -e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046).

I've tried refining my question, and even a major re-write for the question about nodes, but I didn't even notice the question get bumped in the unanswered/newest queue and the view count didn't change much -maybe 1 more view. Does it get bumped at all or did it just get re-buried *that* quickly?

What have I missed in the overall process?

Comment: Possibly just obscure tags.  There's nothing wrong with the questions.  It's not you, it's us as a community.  If things are really not working consider a bounty for extra attention.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I thought about tags being obscure with math, but not with the ruby one. So I thought there was something else going on.

Comment: People may also be intimidated by the sheer size of the questions. They take up more than one screenful on my monitor, and I have an HD monitor in portrait...

Comment: That could also be an issue - I admit - I opened them now and couldn't make myself to read them. If you could somehow simplify and summarize them, it could be better. Not that I could answer them anyway - I am still a beginner in all this stuff. But if they looked intriguing enough, I might have followed them - to check for answers.

Comment: The questions are too wordy, get to the point quicker. As it is it's going to take up a lot of time that a potential answerer could have used answering other easier to digest questions.

Comment: @KevinB: I can "get to the point quicker" by removing what I've already researched, but that doesn't look like a good idea. It might just lead to everyone's time being wasted due to answers proposing things that have already been attempted. My research efforts are what seem to take most of the space. How do you clearly and accurately explain more complex problems with less words? Can you provide more concrete feedback?

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for the down vote here?

Comment: Looking at the first question, my issue with it is more so on the organization than the size. There are a few sentences here and there that are unimportant, but overall they wouldn't detract from the question if the problem was closer to the top of the question. If you described the problem first, reading through the math portion would be more useful because as you're reading through it,  you'd be looking causes of said problem. As it's currently organized, it's more useful to skip the math and read the problem first, then double back.

Comment: Its entirely possible that these questions are, you know, difficult. You wouldn't come here if you could solve them, and I assume the majority of users on this site are like me, without the time to settle down and solve a complex problem.

Comment: @KevinB: That seems fair. Maybe I've not been doing that as well as I thought, even after a re-write. It seems to be a combination of things. Should I just group all the questions at the top and then provide the "background" later in the posts?

Comment: @kirkpatt: That's probably true to some extent, but with so many eyes looking, the problem is bound to be relatively "trivial" for at least someone, right? There're certainly some deep/complex questions that have received quite a bit of attention, like this one about [branch prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/4594973).

Comment: I don't think changing the organization would actually result in more traction though. This does seem to be a pretty niche question, a bounty might be more... effective.

Comment: @KevinB: I'll re-work the nodes post when I get a bit more time today. Would the edit actually bump the question in the queue? I've read that it editing questions bumps them to the front of the page, but I don't think I've ever seen this first hand with my questions.

Comment: @ray Yes, the edit will bump the post. I'm not sure if anyone pays attention to the active tab, since there's so much noise, however.

Comment: I'm seeing many posts in meta trying to attract attention to questions without putting a bounty on them first, from those who has enough rep to put bounties, those who have been here long enough to surely know about bounties.

Comment: If I were you I would shoot for a 250 point bounty.

Comment: You could use the [inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid) and apply [some formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site/17205#17205). Catchy titles and being buzzword-compliant may also help. The titles for the two example questions look a little bit too generic - they should promise more drama. Look at newspapers for examples.

Comment: [Using your real name (or to some degree thereof)](https://ckjy.quora.com/Programming-Question-Policy-Take-2) may help. *"Because of this norm, people who use common names on Stack Overflow are seen differently to people who use random-looking names ... The latter category deserves special mention: for example, Paul Tomblin refers to such users as "drive-bys" (Paul Tomblin's answer to Why don't people who know an answer on Stack Overflow answer the question?), who are not generally seen as bona fide members of the Stack Overflow community."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I'll keep the inverted pyramid in mind. I'll mix it with lots of bold and lists in the future, too :) I think the advice you quote seems incomplete. The number of up-voted and/or accepted answers should also count towards judging whether someone is a "drive-by" or a good member of the community. A name by itself might give a clue, but is probably not enough in most cases, imho.

Comment: Re: _Am I just asking in the wrong place here (e.g. should I've gone to the gamedev, or math sites instead of SO)?_ If I can ask a question on a smaller site, I usually do. Stack Overflow is so huge nowadays that tons of decent questions fall through the cracks and tons more borderline ones get endlessly raked through the coals trying to determine if they should be closed. I've found smaller sites typically friendlier and more hungry for anything halfway decent. Your scene graph question could've gone to game dev or CG, for instance.

Comment: I added a bounty and got some attention, including two responses. Improvement.

Comment: @TJ: This meta post is not intended to "attract attention to questions", as you said. It's explicitly intended to see what feedback I'd get and provided those questions as examples. Clearly, if I had wanted to attract attention, I would not have waited 3+ *months* for the ruby-related post before posting here... You should've taken that into consideration before making that claim.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I look at your first two questions, see that you've obviously thought about them a lot, and move on. I generally only try to help with questions where the person is just not very familiar with the technology.

Comment: I have noticed the pattern quite often, difficult questions attract fewer viewers, and strangely even fewer upvotes, while trivial questions, sometimes showing no research effort, get upvoted. I've had some questions marked "favorite" several times but with no upvotes (not even on answer). It may be that the people visiting difficult questions not only are fewer, but are also more **critical** (with higher standards) than those who visit the trivial questions. Reading the replies to this question will help me improve my own :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, I can explain why [one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942389/correctly-transforming-a-node-relative-to-its-parent) wasn't answered: extremely poor tagging.

The tags for that question are: [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) [matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation) [game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-engine) [transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformation).

The only tags with more than marginal numbers of followers are math and game-engine. "Math" is such a broad category that it encompasses a large amount of stuff. That is, just because someone is following "math" does not mean that they have any idea what to do with your question.

And "game-engine" is... well, let's be honest. It's a cesspool; it's a horrible place where primarily crap questions get asked and primarily answered by people who don't know much about stuff.

The people who could answer it are those with 3D graphics-based skillsets. But they generally don't follow "math", because most math questions aren't about math as it applies to graphics. They also generally don't follow "matrix", "rotation", or "transformation".

Therefore, nobody answered it because nobody who could *ever saw it*.

People with 3D graphics skillsets, the people you were aiming for, are more likely to patrol tags for their particular domain. Many such users patrol API-specific tags like [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx) or [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl), because a lot of general graphics questions will get those tags even if the question isn't about the API itself. The [3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d) also sees a fair amount of use.

For your question, which is based in pseudocode (and thus doesn't have a language tag) and doesn't apply to any graphics API (and thus doesn't have an API tag), it effectively slipped through the cracks.

Comment: I've updated the tags for the question as per recommendations. +1

Answer (score 63):

Good questions tend not to get answers, because they are difficult.

Rather, the kind of question that actually gets answered are the *trivial* questions that should almost always be closed as duplicates, but aren't - at least not soon enough to provide the quick-answerers with their sweet sweet fake internet points.

This isn't how the StackOverflow is *supposed* to work, but it's how it *does* work.

Comment: Are there discussions on how the SO process could potentially be improved to encourage the way this is *supposed* to work?

Comment: Give people negative votes if they answer a question that gets closed within a day?

Comment: But that seems more like a community effort/etiquette rather than a process "built into" the site. And we already know that the current process is probably lacking in this area.

Comment: You didn't split the infinitive!  Now you are my hero :-D

Comment: Sad but true. Good, descriptive questions cannot be answered FGITW style and therefore, a lot of possible answerers don't bother to read them, let alone craft an answer (which - speaking from the rep-whore perspective - makes perfect sense. In the time it takes to read one of the OP's questions, you can easily answer a couple of the poor "I didn't bother to Google, let alone read the documentation" crap ones).

Comment: The problem is that there's plenty of people that can answer trivial questions and only few people that can answer *Actual* questions. Of this small subset only few people have time to *actually answer* these question. Given that the majority of questions is trivial even people that are capable and have time to answer good questions end up wasting time answering trivial questions (or simply reading them, cause 99% are trivial).  The only way to change this would be to somehow make people that can answer questions only *see* "hard" questions.

Comment: @Bakuriu: If the system can suddenly tells the difference between "easy" questions and "hard" questions, then rep-whoring would become a lot easier; people would simply filter *out* the hard ones and focus on the easy ones instead. Even those who can answer the hard ones might be tempted to only focus on these... unless hard questions were to be worth more rep for those investing more time/effort into them. The system would become more complicated overall, so this would probably need a lot more thought, and might turn out to be a *bad* idea anyway. All questions should be treated equally.

Comment: @ray The system *can* figure it out, but only after the fact - if the question is closed quickly.

Comment: @o11c: I don't think a question being closed quickly *necessarily* implies that it was "easy" to answer. Some difficult questions might simply be off-topic, right?

Comment: @ray Well, people shouldn't be punished for answering those too.

Comment: @o11c: I agree. I don't think I suggested that people should be punished for answering specific kinds of questions.

Comment: @ray I doubt that. The number of "hard" question is a little percentage of the overall number of questions asked, so that kind of effect wouldn't be really significant since filtering out hard question wouldn't really do much.

Answer (score 22):

## Your questions need descriptive titles

*Workaround for XML to Hash Conversion Issue?*—The only thing I know here is that you have an "issue" (and basically every on SO has issues) related to XML and Hashes.

If someone reads a title, and from the title it looks like they could answer, they would say "oh cool, I could probably answer that."

If the title doesn't describe the problem enough that a reader could guess at the details, and how it would be fixed, he's not so likely to open that question up and read through it.

Based on a brief look at your question, I'd recommend something more like

> **XML to Hash conversion—Nori dropping the attributes of the deepest XML elements**

Now people who can help (people who know about xml, Nori, and maybe have experienced the same problem) can see what the actual problem is, and think "I might be able to help here".

## Personal rant

In this age we are drowning in a flood of clickbait titles: "I did this ONE TRICK and now I own 3 unicorns", "You'd never believe how I screwed up this time!", "I force-pushed to master, what my boss does next will blow your mind."

Please join me in the fight to accurately describe the content with proper titles. Please.

Comment: *Top ten ways to get an answer* or *Seven biggest mistakes when asking*. We must read different things.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed title. I've updated the the question with your recommendation. +1

Comment: +1 for rant. So true. I actually refuse to click these links just on principle.

Comment: I learned that click-bait titles are a good indicator of low-quality content - even before I encountered the term *click-bait*.

Comment: @Almo: But click-bait posts probably deserve at least a visit to get down-voted or flagged. Genuinely bad content should be cleaned up and removed.

Comment: Agreed, I meant that I don't click click-bait links on Facebook. Sorry I was unclear. :)

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes there just isn't a good answer to the question.

For example, consider your question: [Workaround for XML to Hash Conversion Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735053/866026). As I understand it, you have encountered a known bug in a library you are using and the developer of that library has acknowledged the bug but has not yet come up with a solution to the bug. Other than providing a patch to the library (which is clearly out-of-scope for SO), what kind of answer could be provided? Let's consider a few:

- If there is a hack to trick the library into working, then the most likely source of such a hack would be the people involved in the discussion about the bug. Those people may or may not be here on SO, but they are definitely watching/following the bug report. If such an answer exists, then SO may be the wrong place to ask.

  As an aside, I have no direct knowledge about the topic of that question. However, as a maintainer of an unrelated library for many years, I've encountered similar questions from time to time. I've always been happy to offer a workaround when one exists for free, but if developing a workaround takes as much effort as developing a fix, I'll work on the fix rather than the workaround.
- An alternate library/tool may exist which does not contain such a bug. However, SO is not a tool recommendation site. In fact, you almost ask for a recommendation directly, although it falls apart by the end of that paragraph. Actually, if you cleaned that paragraph up, I'd be inclined to vote to close the question citing a 'recommendation request' as the reason.

  However, I can see that you have done your best to follow the advice to "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it" instead of asking for a recommendation. Regardless, the answer may simply be to wait for the bug to be fixed (or to dig in and fix the bug yourself). And, well, that's not really something anyone is likely to put in an answer.

Again, there simply may not be an answer to your question. In fact, I see a number of up-votes and at least one star on your question (which may or may not have happened after you posting on meta), which suggests others would also like to receive an answer. Given the lack of other responses, that also suggests that anyone else who has knowledge about your question does not know the answer.

Comment: I think you make some valid points, although I don't think the question would get anywhere close to being a 'tool recommendation' request. I had tried a few gems already (don't immediately remember the prior 2), but they were more complicated to use and I don't remember what prompted me to change back then. The workaround request is basically to see if anyone was aware of at least a hack solution that could be implemented and clearly documented on my side so that I could move forward with it until the bug got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735053/1997232) looks like a problem you are able to reproduce. With long-long-long-... (really long) explanation. Most of people just open your question, scroll down and close.

Instead of detailed explanation you can rather create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as short as you can) and 1 paragraph or explanation. That would allow *lazy* people simply *try* your code, confirm/decline problem and look for solution by trying simple things.

Other question seems also very long. You really have to work out how to make the simplest case sufficient to reproduce your problem, removing all extra.

Also tags, I don't know [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), but then you say `Nokogori`, `Nori`, etc.. are those tags? Developers are the best help when it comes to their library question, which you mark using tags.

Comment: Long explanations are fine, but a short **TL;DR** section at the top with a short version of the specific question is very helpful.  Make sure the real question isn't buried inside a huge amount of text.

Comment: I provide MCVEs when possible (i.e. I did this on the Nori question), but the question about node transformations is simply a small part in a larger project and it's not really feasible to post the amount of code that'd be necessary for an MCVE.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think that's a very good point. I've not been consistent in doing that sort of thing, so I'll take that.

Comment: @ray: Always optimize your posts (questions and answers) for people to skim them.  Short paragraphs, section titles in `### headline` font-size, `---` horizontal rules, and bulleted lists are great tools.  e.g. have a look at one of my [highly-voted answers with several sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295).  I have a bullet list as a sort of table of contents, and expand on those points in sections where I bolded the key phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Long explanations are fine, but a short **TL;DR** section at the top with a short version of the question is very helpful.  Make sure the real question isn't buried inside a huge amount of text.

Always optimize your posts (Q or A) for people to skim them.  Short paragraphs, section titles in `### headline` font-size or just regular `**bold**`, horizontal `---` rulers, and bulleted lists are great tools.

Often people who can answer know what you're asking from a very short description.  (Sometimes not, and you can't always know ahead of time, so you shouldn't skimp on details).  Ideally you make it clear what you want to know, and then explain what you've tried and what you already know, and other background stuff, so people answering know where to start, or can find your mistake.

Long questions are fine as long as it's clear that most of it is only non-essential background / what you've tried.

I think [one of my long-ish answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295) with several sections is a pretty good example of formatting. I have a bullet list as a sort of table of contents, and expand on those points in sections where I bolded the key phrase.